# How to remove characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g503793-d571919-r748731637-Premier_Inn_Waltham_Abbey_hotel-Waltham_Abbey_Essex_England.html#review748731637

Is there a way to remove anything after # from this URL in Javascript

Answer (score 2):

You could split it by `#` then take the first element

```js
const url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g503793-d571919-r748731637-Premier_Inn_Waltham_Abbey_hotel-Waltham_Abbey_Essex_England.html#review748731637'

console.log(url.split('#')[0])
```

Or use regex to match the specific group

```js
const url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g503793-d571919-r748731637-Premier_Inn_Waltham_Abbey_hotel-Waltham_Abbey_Essex_England.html#review748731637'

const [_, res] = /(.*)#.*/.exec(url)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

use String.split()

```
const url = "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g503793-d571919-r748731637-Premier_Inn_Waltham_Abbey_hotel-Waltham_Abbey_Essex_England.html#review748731637"

firstPartUrl = url.split('#')[0]
```